# picklist values and soql query sort order

Tags: soql

I have a picklist with values 2000,2001,2002,2003,...When I used below query records are not sorting on **visualforce page** .
From [order by docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm)   sorting of picklist is a special case "picklist sorting is defined by the picklist sort determined during setup."

```
 list<Some_Object__c> olist = [SELECT id,Your_Picklist_field__c FROM Some_Object__c ORDER BY Your_Picklist_field__c DESC];
```

Comment: can you add the code where you create the picklist?  If you use are using a map whatsoever, that's probably what's causing the mis-ordering.

Comment: Also, your soql should read:  "SELECT id,Your_Picklist_field__c FROM Some_Object__c ORDER BY Your_Picklist_field__c DESC"

Comment: I am not creating picklist in code.

Comment: Perhaps you are wanting it to sort like a list of numbers, but instead it is sorting like a list of strings.

Comment: yes I want to sort like a number

Comment: `order by` being effected by picklist configuration would be news to me, and the documentation is often incorrect.  May be the case here but I am not sure.

Comment: @PhilR The same effect is visible in reports. Try it out sometime; sort an opportunity report by stage name.

Answer (score 3):

```
picklist sorting is defined by the picklist sort determined during setup.
```

this means your data is returned in same order as in picklist field.

You can use `Comparable Interface` to sort your list by any wanted value

```
global class Employee implements Comparable {

public Long id;
public String name;
public String phone;

// Constructor 

public Employee(Long i, String n, String p) {
    id = i;
    name = n;
    phone = p;
}

// Implement the compareTo() method 

global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    Employee compareToEmp = (Employee)compareTo;
    if (id == compareToEmp.id) return 0;
    if (id > compareToEmp.id) return 1;
    return -1;        
}
}
```

check http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_comparable.htm

Comment: I want the sorting like a number.Is it not possible with just order by in soql query

Comment: @sf.dev SOQL ordering is indeed in picklist order, not numeric order. If you wanted numeric order, use a number-type field.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have picklist order as 2000,2001,2002,2003 ..but still it is not sorting  in picklist order

Comment: who wants to make an apexfiddle site

Comment: @PhilR Like jsfiddle? I'd be game to try that out.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Object setup, go the Picklist field in question, and there are options there where you can change the ordering of the Picklist values

Comment: picklist values are sorted under setup.But when you try to display muliple records on vf page order by this picklist ...sorting is not working

Comment: you mean you need different picklist-sorts for different Record Types?   If what SF is naturally giving is not sufficing, I suggest generating your own picklists in your VF Controller

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be using a formula field to convert the picklist to a type number, then sort on that formula field.

Formula Field

```
As_Number__c = VALUE(TEXT(My_Picklist__c))
```

SOQL

```
SELECT <whatever> ORDER BY As_Number__c DESC
```

Comment: comma is displaying.How to remove comma